Adjusting the control panel in GEE
I try to adjust the the size and distance of customized drawing tool control panel, but it failed. Specifically, I want to reduce the size of drawing sympols and control panel and move the control panel further up to the top left (see picture below). The red arrow indicated the position I want, while the size of the control panle should be the size of the green box. Here is the sample code.
var drawingTools = Map.drawingTools();
Map.setControlVisibility(false)
drawingTools.setShown(false);

while (drawingTools.layers().length() > 0) {
  var layer = drawingTools.layers().get(0);
  drawingTools.layers().remove(layer);
}

var dummyGeometry = ui.Map.GeometryLayer({
  geometries: null, 
  name: 'geometry', 
  color: '23cba7'
});


drawingTools.layers().add(dummyGeometry);


function clearGeometry() {
  var layers = drawingTools.layers();
  layers.get(0).geometries().remove(layers.get(0).geometries().get(0));
}

function drawRectangle() {
  clearGeometry();
  drawingTools.setShape('rectangle');
  drawingTools.draw();
}

function drawPolygon() {
  clearGeometry();
  drawingTools.setShape('polygon');
  drawingTools.draw();
}

var controlPanelSymbols = {
  rectangle: '⬛',
  polygon: '',
};

var controlPanel = ui.Panel({
  widgets: [
    ui.Button({
      label: controlPanelSymbols.rectangle,
      onClick: drawRectangle,
      style: {stretch: 'horizontal'
      }
    }),
    ui.Button({
      label: controlPanelSymbols.polygon,
      onClick: drawPolygon,
      style: {stretch: 'horizontal'
      }
    })
  ],
  style: {position: 'top-left'
  },
  layout: ui.Panel.Layout.Flow('horizontal'),
});

Map.add(controlPanel)


